# Using GSON annotations in JSON file to get the values in a java file?

Tags: java, json

I am new to JSON.I am looking at the possibility of using  GSON annotations in JSON file and getting the values in  JSON file to a Java file.I tried this using  "@serializedname" in JSON file but was unsuccesful.Below posted is my ".JSON" file and the ".java" files.

JSON file has got all the values  and I'm trying to get those values into the .JAVA file

```
  {

 "valuess": [
   {
  "color": "red",
  "value": "#f00"
},
{
  "color": "green",
  "value": "#0f0"
},
{
  "color": "blue",
  "value": "#00f"
},
{
  "color": "cyan",
  "value": "#0ff"
},
{
  "color": "magenta",
  "value": "#f0f"
},
{
  "color": "yellow",
  "value": "#ff0"
},
{
  "color": "black",
  "value": "#000"
}
] 
}
```

This is the .Java file i have

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;
public class file2
{
@SerializedName("valuess")
private List<valuess> vales;

public void setValuess(List<valuess>valuess)
{
   this.vales = valuess;
}
public List<valuess> getVales()
{
    return vales;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Values are"+vales;
}
}
```

Values.java

```
public class Values {


  private String color;
  private  String value;
  Values()
  {

  }
 Values(String Color,String Value)
  {
    this.color=Color;
    this.value = Value;
  }
 public void setColor(String Color)
 {
   this.color = Color;
 }
public void setValue(String Value)
{
    this.value = Value;
}
public String getColor()
{
    return color;
}
public String getValue()
{
    return value;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Colors[color="+color+"value="+value+"]";
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be your File2 class code

```
public class File2
{
    private Valuess[] valuess;

    public Valuess[] getValuess ()
    {
        return valuess;
    }

    public void setValuess (Valuess[] valuess)
    {
        this.valuess = valuess;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [valuess = "+valuess+"]";
    }
}
```

this should be your Valuess class code

```
public class Valuess
{
    private String color;

    private String value;

    public String getColor ()
    {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor (String color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getValue ()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [color = "+color+", value = "+value+"]";
    }
}
```

Now you can call the fromJson(String json, Class classOfT) method to convert the JSON to Object :

```
File2 file2 = new Gson.fromJson(your_json_string_here, File2.class);
```